# How to make a button change a label

Tags: java, android, button, label

I am new to java, and I am making a small little game that says "yes" or "no" when the user presses a button. I am not sure how to code to make the label change based on the user pushing the button. The code is below. Any other problems that you see with the code, I am interested in discovering those also.

```
public class FirstProject extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView answerTextView;
EditText name1Txt;
EditText name2Txt;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        answerTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answerLbl);
        name1Txt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameoneTxt);
        name2Txt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name2Txt);

        Button compBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.compBtn);
        compBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            //where I want to make the button react

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: read the documentation before posting questions

Answer (score 0):

Every EditText has a method you have to call

[EditText#setText(...);](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(java.lang.CharSequence))

## Example:

```
 name1Txt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameoneTxt);
        name2Txt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name2Txt);

        Button compBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.compBtn);
        compBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            //where I want to make the button react
            name1Txt.setText("Hello..."); 
            name2Txt.setText("...world"); 
            }
        });
```